# Change shape of marker-arrowhead

Tags: jointjs

I want to change the image of marker-arrowheads to achieve uniformity for my web application.

[Link Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VZwW.png)

Is there a simple and possible way to change the image of marker-arrowheads.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by following the below mentioned solution:

link.attr({

'.marker-arrowhead[end="source"]': { fill: 'red', d: 'M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z' },

'.marker-arrowhead[end="target"]': { fill: 'yellow', d: 'M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z' }

});

Comment: But, I'm unable to change the fill color for new path. Even if I change the color of fill to be different, I see no difference.